# Front and back audio jack of B450M DS3H-CF not detected -> no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.04, audio-jack

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a system with a Gigabyte B450M DS3H-CF and AMD Ryzen 5 and **the front and back audio microjack aren't working**. They are **not detected** in the sound settings, only Dummy audio is available. I updated to the very last ubuntu kernel availabe: 5.6.11. I also tried with an old 5.2.21 kernel as I read that some audio drivers were disabled in 5.3 and newer, but the audio jack aren't detected with 5.2.21 too. I even tried with 5.7-rc5 just to see, same result.

When I plug a screen in HDM, **it is detected and sound is working** but I am still unable to select the audio jack in the settings.

The `HD Audio Controller` was disabled in the BIOS. I enabled it and the system is detecting two devices, the HDMI and the jack:

```
inxi -SMA
System:    Host: euclide Kernel: 5.6.11-050611-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450M DS3H v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450M DS3H-CF v: x.x serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: F50 
           date: 11/27/2019 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.6.11-050611-generic
```

```
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 80
    Memory at fcb88000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
--
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 81
    Memory at fcb80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
```

However, alsa mixer and pulseaudio still can't reach the jack, they are only providing HDMI:

```
aplay -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

```
pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb88000 irq 79"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:07:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "15de"
        device.product.name = "Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Sortie Digital Stereo (HDMI) (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Sortie Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Sortie Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Sortie Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Sortie Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Sortie Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Sortie Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Sortie Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Sortie Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Éteint (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

**What can I do to make the jack of the motherboard detected by Ubuntu?**

Here is the complete output of `alsa-info`:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.65
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Tue May 12 10:41:07 UTC 2020


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name:      B450M DS3H
Product Version:   Default string
Firmware Version:  F50
Board Vendor:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Board Name:        B450M DS3H-CF


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0030:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDIF030:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXTHERM:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXVIDEO:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C14:01/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:11/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:12/status   11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:23/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.6.11-050611-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.6.11-050611-generic
Library version:    1.2.2
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb88000 irq 80
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb80000 irq 81


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

07:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
07:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1458:a182]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x1002aa01
Subsystem Id: 0x00aa0100
Revision Id: 0x100700
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x70]: 32000 44100 48000
    bits [0x2]: 16
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x03 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=2, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x08 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x09 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x585600f0: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x08
Node 0x0a [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x0b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x585600f0: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0a
Node 0x0c [Audio Output] wcaps 0x221: Stereo Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x585600f0: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  7 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/controlC1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  6 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  5 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 May 12 12:39 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 May 12 12:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 220 May 12 12:39 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 May 12 12:39 pci-0000:07:00.1 -> ../controlC0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 May 12 12:39 pci-0000:07:00.6 -> ../controlC1


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card Generic_1

Card hw:0 'Generic_1'/'HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb88000 irq 80'
  Mixer name    : 'ATI R6xx HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700'
  Controls      : 21
  Simple ctrls  : 3
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]

!!-------Mixer controls for card Generic

Card hw:1 'Generic'/'HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb80000 irq 81'
  Mixer name    : ''
  Components    : ''
  Controls      : 0
  Simple ctrls  : 0


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.Generic_1 {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        index 1
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.9 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        index 1
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.10 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        index 1
        value '0482000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.11 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        index 1
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.12 {
        iface PCM
        device 7
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.13 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=8 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.14 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        index 2
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.15 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        index 2
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.16 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        index 2
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.17 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        index 2
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.18 {
        iface PCM
        device 8
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.19 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.20 {
        iface PCM
        device 7
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.21 {
        iface PCM
        device 8
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
}
state.Generic {
    control {
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

aesni_intel
ahci
amd_iommu_v2
amdgpu
autofs4
ccp
cec
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
edac_mce_amd
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
gpio_amdpt
gpio_generic
gpu_sched
hid
hid_generic
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_piix4
input_leds
ip_tables
joydev
k10temp
kvm
libahci
lp
mac_hid
nls_iso8859_1
nvme
nvme_core
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
r8169
rc_core
realtek
sch_fq_codel
snd
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer
soundcore
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
ttm
usbhid
video
wmi
wmi_bmof
x_tables


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_pin_configs:
0x03 0x185600f0
0x05 0x185600f0
0x07 0x185600f0
0x09 0x585600f0
0x0b 0x585600f0
0x0d 0x585600f0

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.136114] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.136114] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.136115] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    4.838663] [drm] add ip block number 8 <vcn_v1_0>
[    4.840211] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.845899] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.6: no codecs found!
[    4.849597] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input10
[    4.849660] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input11
[    4.849710] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0/input12
[    4.866952] [drm] BIOS signature incorrect 0 0
--
[    5.138380] [drm] Display Core initialized with v3.2.69!
[    5.152892] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: bound 0000:07:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    5.165821] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-tools-gui                             1.1.7-1ubuntu1                             amd64        GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.2-1                                    all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1                                    all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu1                             amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

For the record, `hdajackretask` (from `alsa-tools-gui`) also see only the HDMI output.